# how do you deploy forge viewer on amazon? #autodesk #forge viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

I'm new to forge. i've already got the aws setup and have the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey. when I run the viewer I get an "ConfigError: Missing region in config"

For some strange reason even removed the client id and client secret. but it doesn't say anything about the client ID and client key

```
const awsParamStore = require( 'aws-param-store' );


awsParamStore.getParametersByPath(" https://s3aecshare.s3.af-south-1.amazonaws.com/RVT_Test/rac_basic_sample_project.rvt");

const awsFlag = process.env.FORGE_AWS_FLAG;
//const paramStore = {"region": process.env.AWS_REGION}
const paramStore = {"region": "af-south-1"}

const clientId = process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_ID;
//const clientId ="-----------------------------";

//const clientSecret = process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET;
const clientSecret = "---------------------------";

// Autodesk Forge AWS configuration for SSM service
module.exports = {

    // Required scopes for your application on server-side
    scopeInternal: ['bucket:create', 'bucket:read', 'data:read', 'data:create', 'data:write'],
    // Required scope of the token sent to the client
    scopePublic: ['viewables:read'],
    
    getParamStore: function() {
        // If not running on AWS, paramStore requires access and secret AWS Keys
        if (awsFlag){
            return paramStore;
        }else{
            paramStore.credentials = 
            {
                "accessKeyId" : "-------------------------------------",
                "secretAccessKey" :"--------------------------------------"
            };
        }
        return paramStore;                        
    },
    
    forgeAWSClientId: async function() {
        let parameter = await awsParamStore.getParameter( clientId , this.getParamStore());
        return parameter.Value;
    },

    forgeAWSClientSecret: async function() {
        let parameter = await awsParamStore.getParameter( clientSecret ,this.getParamStore());
        return parameter.Value;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What I see in your snippet code is some logic that is trying to retrieve keys from AWS, but nothing actually related to Forge. Can you share the rest of your implementation here as well?

Comment: Thank you for your response @PetrBroz , i'm  trying to host the files on amazon. So when i run the app, it pulls from aws I think maybe I should ask aws for support?

Comment: Yes, if you're having some issues with retrieving data from aws-param-store due to region settings, you'll probably need to ask their support.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Forge Viewer itself is a JavaScript library. You do not need to deploy it anywhere, just include the following tags in the `<head>` of your HTML markup:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```